# If I add PropTypes, do I need to check typeof?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a prop `onNotifyChange` which is a function and I call it in the `onChange` of an input.

And it has a PropType for `func`.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    onNotifyChange: PropTypes.func,
}
```

When calling `onNotifyChange`, do I need to check `typeof`

```
const onChange = e => {
    // do some stuff
    if(onNotifyChange && typeof onNotifyChange === 'function'){
        onNotifyChange()
    }
}
```

or just checking if it's falsy?

```
const onChange = e => {
    // do some stuff
    if(onNotifyChange){
        onNotifyChange()
    }
}
```

Does `PropTypes.bar` removes the need for checking `typeof foo === 'bar'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to check the types of your props even when using `prop-types`. The `prop-types` library gives you runtime warnings in the development mode of React.

In the example below we are using the development build of React. We have a component `H1` with required function prop. Notice when using the `H1` component within `App`, without passing a value for the `className` prop, an error is thrown, **and** `prop-types` has logged a warning.

So, you cannot rely on `prop-types` to prevent bad props being passed down to children.

```js
function H1({ className, children }) {
  // this will throw if className is not a function
  return <h1 className={className()}>{children}</h1>
}

H1.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.func.required
} 

function App() {
  return <H1>Test</H1>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id=root></div>
```

To prevent this kind of thing happening at runtime you can:

- declare a default value for the prop
- do validation on the value of the prop within the component

Even better, you can do both, as in the example below:

```js
function H1({ className, children }) {
  /* do some validation of your props 
     (throwing here to demonstrate that the default prop set below 
     works - I do not recommend throwing errors within components
     like this unless you know what you're doing, e.g. have an error
     boundary to catch behaviour like this) */
  if (typeof className !== "function") {
    throw new Error("expecting className prop to be function")
  }
  return <h1 className={className()}>{children}</h1>
}

H1.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.func.required
} 

H1.defaultProps = {
  className: () => ""
}

function App() {
  return <H1>Test</H1>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id=root></div>
```

This way your application will not crash due to a bad prop value, and in development mode you will see the warning logged by `prop-types`.

Comment: Throwing an error will generally cause the app to fail, just in a controlled fashion. Littering production code with type checking that can almost always be caught during development seems overkill--if you're throwing errors based on property types then you don't need prop types at all; you're simply adding another, less-attention-grabbing mechanism on top of the hard-coded checking.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not suggesting you throw an actual error in production, just doing that here to demonstrate that using default props works. I will make that clear in my answer - thanks for raising.

Answer (score 2):

It would be advisable to define defaultProps.

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    onNotifyChange: () => false
}
```

This would take care of the scenario where in you "forget" to pass `onNotifyChange`.

Without defining defaultProps, you would run into,

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this10.props.onNotifyChange is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends: In general, no; in practice... maybe.

Type checking does not (normally) happen in a production build. If you have dynamically-constructed properties where the type might be invalid then you'd still need some form of error handling.

Comment: Does PropTypes even really add any protection in non-prod builds, other than logging some warnings to the console?

Comment: @Nick Define "protection". It checks types--it's not a replacement for a type system; it's a development aid intended to warn on one type of error.

Comment: Well, I guess what I'm saying is that guarding code in your app by using `typeof` can prevent errors whereas I don't think using PropTypes will _ever_ prevent errors, unless you count a console warning as preventive because the dev now knows to go fix something

Comment: @Nick Of course using `typeof` can prevent errors. The point is that that particular (ahem) type of error is more appropriately caught during development. If there's a runtime type error it's almost always caused by either (a) programming error or (b) an unexpected type. An unexpected type is almost always something that should be handled at a different point in the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

From the [prop-types package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

> and warn in development if they don’t match

So `prop-types` only "protect" you from making mistakes **while developing**. It will do nothing when your code is running (besides throwing errors on the console).

If you need hard type checks, use [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)... Altough even those are only during dev+build time, so... Nothing in JS can protect you from wrong types during runtime (aside from explicit checks as you write), because it's a weakly typed language after all.